# Query on Sling Custom login module

Tags: ldap, aem, jaas, sling

I have created a custom authentication flow to authenticate using an external provider. As per my understanding, here is the flow of execution.

1. `CustomAuthenticationHandler` (extending `DefaultAuthenticationFeedbackHandler` & implementing `AuthenticationHandler`, `AuthenticationFeedbackHandler`): this extracts the credentials and calls the appropriate login module using JAAS configuration.
2. CustomLoginModule (extending `AbstractLoginModule`). This calls the identity provider, assigns additional groups optionally.
3. CustomIdentityProvider (implementing `ExternalIdentityProvider`): This is where authentication should happen by calling the auth API of my external provider.

The authentication is working fine, I mean

1 > 2 > 3 is working fine and I am able to call API and authenticate the user.

I am getting user information from API in (3) and I am passing it to (2) thru CustomUser (extending `ExtenalUser`).

My problem is I am unable to pass the user info from (2) to (1). I need this information in further processing of request, to display on UI.

How can I pass this data from (2) to (1) ?

What I have tried so far?

I have created a AuthInfo object and call setInfoInfo object of LoginModule class. It is not working. None ofthe custom params I set in the authInfo are available in the

```
public boolean authenticationSucceeded(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationInfo authInfo)
```

that I have over written in `CustomAuthenticationHandler` class. How can I get my custom params in `CustomAuthenticationHandler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need 2 and 3. 
In the extractCredentials method you can call API to authenticate and authenticationSucceeded method to assign user to groups.

If you want to use custom params to use then you need to do implement  org.apache.sling.auth.core.spi.AuthenticationInfoPostProcessor this interface in your custom post authentication class.

You can get AuthInfo object in process method

```
@Component
@Service
public class CustomAuthPostProcess implements AuthenticationInfoPostProcessor {
 @Override
public void postProcess(final AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo,
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws LoginException {
 // Your logic
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like passing custom params is not possible. Hence I created an OSGI service which contains a map and using that to transfer these params between AuthHandler and LoginModule (It sure is a work-around).